# How to make some parameters in a function take multiple numbers and return the lowest value

Tags: r, function, apply, sapply

I have the following Function:

```
Double.Historical.Sim.Var <- function(d1, wa=0.75, wb=0.25, pv=1000, cl=0.95) 
   {
   x <- pv
   w <- c(wa,wb)
   Pw <- -pv*w
   loss <- rowSums(t(Pw * t(d1)))
   result <- quantile(loss,0.95)
   return(result)
  }
```

D1 is a dataframe with the returns of 2 stocks (Microsoft and Amazon)
I need a way for the function to take Wa from 0.01 to 1 with wb being (1-wa)
and to tell me with which combination of wa and wb the value of this function is the lowest.

Thanks in advance for any help !!

Comment: What is the point of `x` in the function? Also, if `wb` is a function of `wa`, why have it as a parameter?

Comment: It would help if you provide a concrete example for `d1`. Also, did you mean `0.01` to `1.00` rather than `0.01` to `100`?

Comment: yes 0.01 to 1, d1 is a dataframe with returns of 2 stocks

Comment: The formula is working, it gives you the Value at Risk of a portfolio of two assets (using the basic historical simulation method). What i need now is a way to find which weight of assets (wa and wb) produce the lowest Value at Risk. Thanks for the quick replies :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting the return value of function. Then, call your function iteratively with `sapply` across a sequence to build a matrix of results and filter for needed min value.

```
Double.Historical.Sim.Var <- function(d1, wa=0.75, wb=0.25, pv=1000, cl=0.95) {
   w <- c(wa, wb)
   Pw <- -pv*w
   loss <- rowSums(t(Pw * t(d1)))
   result <- quantile(loss,0.95)
   return(c(wa, wb, result))       # NEW RETURN
}

res_matrix <- sapply(seq(0.01, 1, by=0.01),
                     function(i) Double.Historical.Sim.Var(d1, wa=i, wb=(1-i))

res_matrix[which.min(res_matrix[3,]),]
```

Comment: res_matrix[which.min(res_matrix[,3]),]     what is the purpose of the 3 in there?

Comment: Actually, the 3 should be row not column. And please remove long comment of hard to read code and feel free to answer your own post below. However, if this solution helped inspire final answer, feel free to accept. You should not need multiple `sapply` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to parfait, the answer in case anyone ever needs it is the following

```
bHS.mv <- function(wa, P, rets){
w <- c(wa, 1-wa)
Pw <- -P*w
loss <- rowSums(t(Pw * t(rets)))
result <- quantile(loss, 0.95)
return(c(wa, result))

wts <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
sapply(wts, bHS.mv, 2000, Port.Vol.Ad)
minvar <- sapply(wts, bHS.mv, 2000, Port.Vol.Ad)

minvar[,which.min(minvar[2,])]
```

This gets you at what weights a portfolio of 2 risks factos has the minimum value at risk